# 더 sounds like tteo (fortis) instead of deo (lenis) in a rapping part of K-Pop?

Tags: pronunciation

Here it is from 1:20-1:21. [link](https://youtu.be/ogUI4eeHsCg?t=120)
It at least sounds like fortis to me. This part is rapped by a Japanese person (Sakura), but I figure K-Pop has some regulations to make sure they pronounce it at least 90% correct?

Comment: why do you assume that?

Comment: @user17915 added "It at least sounds like that to me." to the description

Comment: I can tell that Sakura has a bit of Japanese accent but her pronunciation is OK. To me, it sounds `tteo` than `deo` but it is still acceptable enough to be `더`. It doesn't sound like `떠` or `터`.

Comment: I have just deleted my answer, which mentioned auditory illusions and the environment around the character 더, because two downvoted it without leaving any reasons in the comment section. I hope they post their own answers much better than mine.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, you wrote "from 1:20-1:21." but I think it's from 2:00 - 2:01. 

Anyway, I think Sakura sings the 더 correctly. ㄷ can be pronounce [t] or [d] but when the ㄷ is at the beginning of a word is almost always pronounce as a [t] and when the ㄷ is in the middle of a word then it's often pronounce as [d] but it depends if there's a 받침 (final consonant) to the previous syllable and other spelling rules I quite don't remember all. 

When it's like that the ㄷ is pronounce more like a "t".

Comment: I'm not into Kpop or Sakura but like to contribute to the use of 더 (more) and 덜 (less). 덜걱정 (less worry), 더기도(more pray) will bring you 평화 (peace).

Answer (score 1):

Her pronunciation is not accurate IMO. I am native Korean but without lyrics in the video clip, I don't even know what she says for "더" part. It's like "우리 서로에게 ?#$#? 끌려" to me. I don't think there is regulation or such a thing but it's just common problem with idol group especially when the group has a foreigner member(s) in it.